# Is there a .jar launcher for OS X

Tags: java, macos, launcher

I am under the impression that [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html) cannot create launchers for OS X. Correct me, if I am wrong.

I would like to use something similar so I can set the initial heap size/ max heap size for my Java application without using command line options (java -jar -Xmx1024m etc....).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Despite the title, you're not looking for a JAR launcher.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/java/conceptual/java14development/03-javadeployment/javadeployment.html or, in general: https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+java+bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is an [Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13).  It include a properties file (Info.plist) where you can set things like `Xmx`, etc.

You can also use Oracle's [appbundler tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) to create an application bundle.

Another no-brainer option is to create a shell script.  Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar myJar.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, this is obviously the first time I am going through this process, so I appreciate the helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse can export a run configuration as a runnable jar file or a Mac OSX application bundle.
In the run configuration, add the command line options to the VM arguments textbox in the arguments tab.

Comment: I already export it as Runnable Jar but I cannot/ don't know how to specify the initial and maximum heap size this way, which was my main concern.

Comment: In the run configuration, add the command line options to the VM arguments textbox in the arguments tab.